# pip dependencies of dependencies when installed from conda environment.yaml

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I am trying to create a conda environment.yml file for users of a project. One dependency is not distributed by conda, but available with pip+github. I assume based on [this example](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/54e4a91d0da4d659a67e3097040764d3a2f6aa16/tests/conda_env/support/advanced-pip/environment.yml) that I can do this:

```
dependencies
    - pip
    - regular_conda_dep
    - depend_of_blah
    # Install in editable mode.
    - -e git+https://github.com/ourgroup/blah.git
```

But what happens to the dependencies of blah (depend_of_blah)? Will the pip install after the conda so that as long as I am careful to include it gets installed before blah? Later on will blah update cleanly, getting as much as possible from conda?

Or do I need to add --no-deps to the pip line? Is it implied that this is done magically? I don't see a lot of advanced examples that deal with this, but in my experience is that it is a real danger in pip/conda mixes not to use --no-deps, with pip essentially hijacking anything that hasn't been explicitly handled first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conda parses the YAML, and partitions the dependency specifications into a Conda set and a Pip set ([code](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/33a142c16530fcdada6c377486f1c1a385738a96/conda_env/env.py#L169)). Only the Conda set is used to solve and create the initial environment.<sup>**1**</sup> Once the environment has been successfully created, Conda writes all the Pip specifications to a temporary `requirements.txt` ([code](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/33a142c16530fcdada6c377486f1c1a385738a96/conda_env/installers/pip.py#L19)), and then using the `python` in the environment runs the command:

```bash
python -m pip install -U -r <requirements.txt>
```

So, to explicitly answer the question: If all the dependencies of `blah` are installed via Conda *and* they have sufficient versions installed, then Pip should only install `blah` and leave the Conda versions untouched. This is because the default value for `--upgrade-strategy` is `only-if-needed`.

Otherwise, if the Conda dependencies section does not include all the dependencies of `blah`, then Pip will install the necessary dependencies.

---

<sub>**[1]:** Technically, if there are `create_default_packages` set in the Conda configuration, Conda will first create the environment with just these packages, then subsequently install the dependencies specified in the YAML file.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

You can tell pip to ignore dependencies via environment variables

```
PIP_NO_DEPS=1 conda env create -f myenv.yaml
```

From the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/?highlight=environment%20variables#environment-variables):

> pip’s command line options can also be set with environment variables
> using the format `PIP_<UPPER_LONG_NAME>` . Dashes (`-`) have to be
> replaced with underscores (`_`).