# pip install with --no-deps in conda environment.yml

Tags: python-3.x, pip, dependencies, conda

I am updating an environment.yml. The only install I have added is:

`pip install -e git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/vissl.git --no-deps`

However, I can not seem to get this working in my environment.yml.

I tried adding:

```
  - pip:
    - -e git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/vissl.git#egg=vissl --no-deps
```

Unfortunately, this results in:

```
Pip subprocess error:
Usage: __main__.py [options]

ERROR: Invalid requirement: -e git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/vissl.git#egg=vissl --no-deps
__main__.py: error: no such option: --no-deps
```

For reference, I am creating the environment using (same happens with conda instead of mamba):

```
mamba env create -f environment.yml
```

It seems like using --no-deps in requirements.txt is not supported ([but might be in the future](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/10837)). Is there any other way to do this install in my environment.yml without pip trying to change the versions of the libraries required by vissl?
Note that the dependencies of vissl are already in the environment, but vissl requirements pin older versions despite vissl working fine with the newer versions.

[Edit] I have a couple pip installs in the environment.yml and I do not want to ignore dependencies for those.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71469865/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bconda%5D+%5Bpip%5D+no-deps

Comment: Thank you, but I do not want to ignore dependencies for the few other pip installs in the environment.yml, so that would unfortunately not work.

Comment: [That PR](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/10837) is the limiting factor, since Conda's `pip:` support in YAML works by creating a temporary requirements.txt. Conda will support it once Pip supports per-requirement `--no-deps`.